# Solr synonyms values ranking issue

Tags: solr

I am facing a problem while listing the solr result on searching a keywords  which is a synonyms value.

Below is the synonyms files for the french site

```
Décorateur, Responsable Visuel, Acheteur
Responsable de la formation, Directeur de la formation
Directeur général,Chef de secteur
```

There is no explicit sorting order define, so currently its solr results are sorted on the basis of score.

If the user search with the keyword "Responsable Visuel" it is displayed at the top, but if search is done with the keyword "Acheteur" it is not displayed at the top but other records related to it synonyms values i.e. Décorateur, Responsable Visuel are displayed and then it displays the result with the keyword "Acheteur". How can I display the result among the synonyms values at the top which is been searched.

Below are code added to schema_extra_fields.xml & schema_extra_types.xml respectively.

```
<fields>
    <dynamicField name="tm_fr_*" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true"/>
    <copyField source="tm_fr_field_ad_title" dest="rank_content_fr"/>
</fields>

<types>
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory" />
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
```

Below is the code to sent the query filter to solr

```
$call_args['params']['qf'][] = 'tm_fr_field_ad_title^90 rank_content_fr';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you index the same content to two different fields, you can weigh those fields independently.  One field would to synonyms expansion, while the other one wouldn't - allowing you to give a higher weight to the second, exact field.

You can index the same content into two different fields by using `<copyField source="content" dest="content_synonyms" />`, and then using `qf=content^2 content_synonyms` when querying to give hits in `content` twice as much weight as hits in `content_synonyms`.

Comment: I tried using the above method but it's not working.